# MongoDB using set compare array in the document with the array being added by the value and update total

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63fe802ce956eaeaab686ce4"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1677542400000"
    }
  },
  "videoId": "7853f3ef01f83d82a82f67052b778a78",
  "timeds": [
    {
      "timed": 122,
      "total": 17
    },
    {
      "timed": 240,
      "total": 10
    },
    {
      "timed": 0,
      "total": 15
    },
    {
      "timed": 47,
      "total": 51
    },
    {
      "timed": 58,
      "total": 1
    }
  ],
  "uniqueViews": 13,
  "completed": 80,
  "views": 1,
  "viewed": 1,
  "left": 3
}
```

I have the above document. It is having data of the video visitors. Like how many of the users viewed the video, completed it, and left at specific time. In the timeds array there timed is the video time in seconds and total is the total visitors that watched the video till that time. I want to add more elements to the timeds array. Suppose following elements I want to insert inside the timeds:

```
[
    {
      "timed": 122,
      "total": 41
    },
    {
      "timed": 240,
      "total": 33
    },
    {
      "timed": 450,
      "total": 15
    },
    {
      "timed": 47,
      "total": 5
    },
    {
      "timed": 96,
      "total": 1
    }
]
```

So as you see in the above array I want to push in the timeds but before pushing I want to check the timed property value if it is already there in the timeds or not. If it is there than the total should get incremented if not then pushed. So the array after pushing the above will be as follows:

```
  "timeds": [
    {
      "timed": 122,
      "total": 58
    },
    {
      "timed": 240,
      "total": 43
    },
    {
      "timed": 0,
      "total": 15
    },
    {
      "timed": 47,
      "total": 56
    },
    {
      "timed": 58,
      "total": 1
    },
    {
      "timed": 450,
      "total": 15
    },
    {
      "timed": 96,
      "total": 1
    }
  ],
```

So timed 122, 240, 47 elements total got incremented and the others got pushed.

```
{
  $set: {
    timeds: {
      $concatArrays: [
        {
          $map: {
            input: visitorDocs.visitors,
            as: "m",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$m.timed",
                    {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$timeds",
                        as: "visitor",
                        in: "$$visitor.timed",
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$m",
                    {
                      total: {
                        $add: ["$$m.total"],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                "$$m",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $filter: {
            input: visitorDocs.visitors,
            as: "timedObj",
            cond: {
              $not: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$timedObj.timed",
                    {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$timeds",
                        as: "visitor",
                        in: "$$visitor.timed",
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    videoId: visitorDocs._id,
  },
  $inc: {
    uniqueViews: 45,
    left: 57,
    completed: 5,
  },
};
```

I tried implementing the above but its full of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you only want to get data through `aggregate` pipeline (case 1) or if you want to update the data in your collection (case 2).

**Case 1:**

Try this (See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZYXvSARHuAz):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      timeds: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$timeds",
          [
            {
              "timed": 122,
              "total": 41
            },
            {
              "timed": 240,
              "total": 33
            },
            {
              "timed": 450,
              "total": 15
            },
            {
              "timed": 47,
              "total": 5
            },
            {
              "timed": 96,
              "total": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$timeds"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$timeds.timed",
      total: {
        $sum: "$timeds.total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      timed: "$_id",
      total: 1,
      _id: 0,
    }
  }
])
```

**Case 2:**

I suggest you to programmatically separate your use case in multiple *idempotent* mongodb queries to update de `timeds` table:

- **query 1:** add the `timeds` with duplication
- **query 2:** remove duplication

Comment: I want to update the data, which is also in one query. I will have a loop of more than 1000s so I want only one query for each loop.